# How to set different ranges for dual axes and assign appropriate standard error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot a bar chart together with a line chart using dual y-axes. I would like to modify the range of the individual y-axis, such as the line chart is over the bar chart. In this case, I wish to have a range from 1-1.5 for `Does` and 0.20-0.5 for `Wight`, so the lines hover the bar chart a bit. However, when I set `limits` after `sec.axis`, only works for the secondary y-axis and the bar chart is gone. I tried to add `break` to give a range, but it did not work out as well. I am wondering if it is possible to manipulate both y-axes individually?

Also, is it possible to have the standard error for each plot (one for the bar chart and one for line chart) when dual-axes are applied? I applied two `stat_summary` for having 2 different `mean_se` (standard error bars), however, only one was plotted.  any suggestion is much appreciated!

```
# dummy data
burger<- tibble(
  Day = rep(1:4,2),
  Dose = c(0.5,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.3),
  Wight = c(0.95,0.92,0.93,0.98,0.95,0.92,0.93,0.98))


  # plot
  ggplot(data= burger, aes(x = Day, y = Dose),group = 1)+
    geom_bar(data= burger, aes(x = Day, y = Wight* (0.98/0.6)), stat = "identity") +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,geom= "errorbar",width=0.6,size=1,aes(y= burger$Dose, width=0.05))+
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,geom= "errorbar",width=0.6,size=1,aes(y= burger$Wight, width=0.05))+
    geom_line (size = 2,aes(group=1))+
    geom_point(aes(colour=Day))  +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Dose", 
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(trans =  ~.*(0.6/0.98) , name = "Wight",limits=c(0.25,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't get the thing about the standard error. Can you explain it a bit better? what do you expect to get out of it?

Comment: @Edo thanks for the reply. I added my attempt of using  `fun.data = mean_se` to generate separate and independent SE  per graph. However, it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: for each day you have only one observation. How can you possibly calculate a standard error?

Comment: @Edo I forgot that I used very simple dummy df here, I just double the values. do you have any suggestion for the separated SEs? cheers!

Comment: if you just double your data your se is still zero. Have a look at my EDIT to the answer. I added a new graph that answers your question (hopefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a +1 and a -1 to set the bars at the same height of the line, also with coord_cartesian you can zoom in the chart without cropping your data. (if you use ylim instead the barchart will disappeared as happened to you).
I adjusted a bit your code too.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

# dummy data
burger <- tibble(Day   = 1:4,
                 Dose  = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3),
                 Wight = c(0.95, 0.92, 0.93, 0.98))


# plot
ggplot(data = burger, aes(x = Day, y = Dose))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = Wight * (0.98/0.6) - 1), stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Day))  +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Dose", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans =  ~(.+1)*(0.6/0.98),
                                         name = "Wight")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.3, 0.6))
```

[image]

EDIT:

This graph answer to the second part of your question.

First of all, I created a random sample of data.

All the objects of the graph are created with `stat_summary`. With `stat_summary` I can apply summary functions to my data: mean with `fun.y`, when I wanted a single result out of my Y var and `mean_se` with `fun.data` when I needed to return a vector usable by geom errorbar.

I added some colours to help you identify each piece and to intuitively relate each value with its errorbar, but you can set the colours you like the most.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(20)

# dummy data
burger<- tibble(
  Day   = rep(1:4, each = 10),
  Dose  = rnorm(40, 0.5, 0.1),
  Wight = rnorm(40, 0.9, 0.1))


# plot
ggplot(data = burger, aes(x = Day))+

  # bars and error
  stat_summary(aes(y = Wight * (0.98/0.6) - 1), 
               fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", 
               fill = "steelblue", alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = Wight * (0.98/0.6) - 1), 
               fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar",
               colour = "steelblue", size = 1.5, width = 0.5) +

  # line/point and error
  stat_summary(aes(y = Dose), fun.data = mean_se, 
               geom = "errorbar", size = 1.5, width = 0.5,
               colour = "coral") +
  stat_summary(aes(y = Dose), fun.y = mean, geom = "line", 
               size = 0.5, colour = "coral") +
  stat_summary(aes(y = Dose, colour = Day), fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 3) +

  # prettier
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Dose", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans =  ~(.+1)*(0.6/0.98),
                                         name = "Wight")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.3, 0.6)) +
  theme_light() +
  scale_color_gradient2(mid = "black", high = "#FFBE5A")
```

[image]

Comment: Bars are exactly as high as in burger data. First one is 0.95 and it touches exactly the 0.95 line that connects to the second y axis. The following two are slightly under as they should and the last one is the highest. Looks fine to me

Comment: Is the solution correct? Do you think something is still missing?

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why you put `-1` in `(0.98/0.6) - 1` and  added `(.+1)` as parameter in `sec_axis`?

Comment: just because you asked " the lines [to] hover the bar chart a bit " :-)

Comment: thanks so much! it works nicely.  I am wondering whether the values of `(0.98/0.6)` were decided arbitrary or based on some calculations, for example, the max value of both `Does` and `weight`. Because  in this plot we can decide the range of `Does`  by doing `(coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.5, 1))`, however it is hard to standardize another y-axis of `weight` when we compare bewteen different datasets

Comment: honestly, I was wondering the same: I thought you had your own reason to choose `0.98/0.6` so I left it as it was. You need to think that what you add/subtract moves your line up and down and what you divide/multiply for stretches or shrink the distance between the points. So, the first one affects the mean, the second one affect the variance. Generally, I sum the difference of the averages and I multiply by the ratio of the variances, so to have the same mean and the same variance between bars and lines

Answer (score 1):

In `ggplot2`, you control the primary y axis, and transform the secondary y axis.  `plotly` allows you to control both axes separately.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = burger) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~Day, y = ~Dose,  name = "Dose") %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~Day, y = ~Wight, yaxis = "y2", name = "Wight") %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(showline = TRUE, side = "left", 
                 title = "Dose", range = c(0.2, 0.6)), 
    yaxis2 = list(showline = TRUE, side = "right", 
                  overlaying = "y",  title = "Wight", range = c(0.9, 1)), 
    showlegend = FALSE,  
    margin = list(pad = 0, b = 50, l = 50, r = 50))
```

[image]